# how to use xmllint in order to get value from xml

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, xml

I have the following **XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Component configuration file -->
<Component>
   <Name>install_env</Name>
   <HelpString>install_env Com</HelpString>
   <Version>1.10.3</Version>
                <Properties>
```

how to get the value of Name tag - **install_env**

by using the tool - **xmllint**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your testfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Component configuration file -->
<Component>
   <Name>install_env</Name>
   <HelpString>install_env Com</HelpString>
   <Version>1.10.3</Version>
</Component>
```

I use **--xpath** argument to get the value of the name tag:

```
user$ test=$(xmllint --xpath "//Component/Name/text()" testfile) 
user$ echo $test
install_env
```

--xpath implies --noout, which prevents xmllint from outputting anything. Redirect the output to a variable or a file.